# Metamask + Chrome: eth_signTypedData_v4 does not exists

Tags: metamask, eip712

I made a dapp that is running on Polygon.
I have been using `eth_signTypedData_v4` for EIP-712 signatures for few weeks.
Everything has been running fine on every browser on desktop and mobile until a couple of weeks ago when suddenly I started getting this message:
`the method eth_signTypedData_v4 does not exist/is not available\`

Did the latest Chrome update "break" `eth_signTypedData_v4`?
Can I replace `eth_signTypedData_v4` with a previous version of it?

Thanks

Comment: What code are you using to call `eth_signTypedData_v4`?

Comment: the code is in the question asked in the openzeppelin forum:
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/meta-transactions-cant-solve-invalid-signature/16392
Sorry I can't paste it here because it's too long